# Add package to svn ignore in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I am using subversive in eclipse to work with svn repo.
I was wondering how it's possible to add a package to svn ignore?
This is because I have consumed a webservices package (not yet added to SVN) and I want to exclude it from being committed to svn.

I tried right click > Team > Add to svn ignore, but the option was disabled.

**UPDATE:** the package name i want to ignore is **remote.webservice** which is a directory called remote and inside it a directory called webservice.

Comment: Using Subclipse it is also not possible to ignore packages. The only option available is "Add to Version Control" - seems to me like a bug in the team provider or in both SVN implementations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround you can ignore a folder by using the "Set property" function on the package one level higher.

Add the following property:

- Property: **svn:ignore**
- Value: **last element of the package to be ignored**

Comment: what will be the value if the package name was remote.webservice, i couldn't figure out the expression, see post update please.

Comment: Use _"Set property"_ on the ***remote*** package and set the property value to ***webservice***.

Comment: but the package appears in eclipse as remote.webservice.

Comment: Create a (temporary) file in the ***remote*** package and it will become visible.

Comment: ok now i ignored the webservice package, but still can't ignore the remote package

Comment: Just do the same - just one level higher using the src directory as a base.

Comment: when i set svn ignore property value to remote on higher package nothing changed, still think that remote backage is new one and doesn't ignore it.

Comment: can you please update the answer to include the details in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Try Windows->Preferences->Team->Ignored resources